# edge-disjoint simple walks

Tags: graph-theory

Let $T$ be a tree on $v$ vertices, $v$ greater than $5$, with precisely four vertices of degree $1$ each and precisely one vertex of degree $4$. Find the degrees of the remaining vertices of
$T$, and show that $T$ can be written as the union of two edge-disjoint simple walks.

Comment: $v$ has to be finite, right? Otherwise there are infinite solutions...

Answer (score 1):

A tree on $v$ vertices has $v-1$ edges, so the sum of all degrees is $2v-2$. The five given degrees add up to $8$, so the degrees of the remaining $v-5$ vertices add up to $2v-10$. Since none of them have degree $1$, it follows that they all have degree $2$.

Now start at the vertex of degree $4$. Each of its four edges leads to a path of zero or more vertices of degree $2$, and since the graph is a tree, these cannot meet each other and must at some point end in a vertex of degree $1$. They can be combined into two pairs arbitrarily to form two edge-disjoint simple walks.

As Andreas pointed out in a comment, this assumes that the graph is finite.

Comment: @victoria: You can visualize the tree as a plus sign ($+$) with knots on some or all of the four arms.